# PostgreSQL SELECT ALL fields in a table as type TEXT

Tags: postgresql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm beginner in SQL

I need a PostgreSQL query that selects ALL fields in a table as type TEXT

I need the query to select all the fields in a single one as *, not that they are defined one by one (field1, field2.. fieldN)

I try with:

```
SELECT *::TEXT FROM table
```

But that can't be done in PostgreSQL.

Is there any way?

Comment: The big question is: Why? It's kind of strange that you first spend time in creating a nice data model, using all the right data types, etc. and when done, move everything back to plain text. I don't think that I've ever seen something like this.

Comment: You can try `SELECT t::text FROM table t` or `SELECT to_json(t) FROM table t`, but then you won't get one text column per table column, rather a single text representing the whole row (which you can parse as record/json syntax).

Comment: @FrankHeikens Hi Frank. I need this query because I am working with Pentaho Data Integration (spoon). I want to optimize the performance of the ETL process and reduce the number of transformations used

Comment: @iván if you want to reduce the number of transformations, then don't transform everything to type `text`?

Comment: @Bergi Hi Bergi. The output of this job is a sql file that contains the inserts of all the records of the input tables (20 tables in this case). I do this as a backup of a small local schema with few records per table. In this file the timestamp type fields are written without quotes in the file, which causes me problems when I want to later execute this script in PostgreSQL. Also input is a common SQL script for all the tables, which are called through a variable <table_name> that is set beforehand with another job.

Comment: Pentaho uses different data types, not just text. I have worked in the past with Pentaho and never had any issues with the data types. And PostgreSQL will never create a backup containing timestamps, without quotes around the timestamp. That would make it an invalid backup, that can not be restored in a PostgreSQL database.